# trouble with 2D memory allocation for string

Tags: c, string, memory, memory-management

I'm trying to understand where I am wrong with the memory allocation.

**The function receives a string, and a letter. the function will create a dynamic string that contains only the words that begin with the letter.**

for example string: "This is a test".
letter: "t"
output: This test
memory allocated: 4*2 bits for the array(char*) . and 4*2 bits allocated to the string themselves(char).

this is the part that allocated the memory.

```
int i=0,word_lenght=0,number_of_words=0,str_len=strlen(str),writer=0,current_word=0;
char** list_of_strings;

number_of_words=count_words_that_start_with_letter(str,letter);
list_of_strings=(char**)malloc(number_of_words*sizeof(char*)); 

for(i=0;i<str_len;i++) 
{
    if(str[i]==letter || str[i]==toupper(letter)) 
    {
        word_lenght = 0;
        while(str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '\0') 
        {
            i++;
            word_lenght++;
        }

        list_of_strings[current_word] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(word_lenght));
        current_word++;

    }       

    else
        while(str[i]!=' ' && str[i]!='\0')
        {
            i++;
        }

}
```

in the following part im copying the letters from the input str to the new allocated one.

```
i=0;
for(current_word=0 ; current_word < number_of_words ; current_word++) 
{
    writer=0;
    if(str[i]==letter || str[i]==toupper(letter)) 
    {
        while(str[i]!=' ' && str[i]!='\0') 
        {
            list_of_strings[current_word][writer]=str[i]; 
            writer++;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s",list_of_strings[current_word]);
    }
    else
        while(str[i]!=' ' && str[i]!='\0')
            i++;
}
```

when i run this program, the output is: This²²²²?Θ

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(word_lenght))` is equal to `malloc(sizeof(int))`. Did you mean `malloc(word_lenght)`? And "length" is the right spelling, not "lenght". Also, you forgot to allocate the space for the NUL-terminator at the end of all the strings.

Comment: You forgot to null-terminate your words.

Comment: i've tried to add the next lines, but still get the same result.    

    `list_of_strings=(char**)malloc(number_of_words*sizeof(char*)+1);
    list_of_strings[current_word] = (char*)malloc(word_lenght+1)`